# Writing this specific sequence in another form

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would one write this sequence: 0, 1, 3, 12, 44, 165, 615 ... 
https://oeis.org/A109437/internal

Without using a recursive formula, and generating a formula that does not  refer back to the previous term to work out the next term.

Kind regards
Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the theory of linear homogeneous recurrences? They can be [solved exactly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%5D%3D3*a%5Bn-1%5D%2B3*a%5Bn-2%5D-a%5Bn-3%5D,%20a%5B-1%5D%3D0,%20a%5B0%5D%3D0,%20a%5B1%5D%3D1):

$$a(n) = \frac{(3+\sqrt{3}) (-1)^{n+1}+(3+2 \sqrt{3}) (2+\sqrt{3})^n -\sqrt{3} (2-\sqrt{3})^n}{6 (3+\sqrt{3})}$$

If you would like to learn how to solve *any* linear homogeneous recurrence relation, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

Comment: Wow that's amazing! Thanks for the quick feedback. I'm definitely going to look into this. This may seem strange, but is there a way to solve it without using square root 3 or any irrational number? If there is a solution, but contains an irrational number, I would love to hear about it :) thanks again!

Comment: Not that I know of. If you are satisfied with my answer, consider upvoting or accepting (though if you are not yet satisfied with the answer, wait to accept).

Comment: I think it is a good solution to start with, but I have seen on that page (the OEIS) that there is already a solution on it, but it contains square root 3. An integer solution would be the best thing possible.

Comment: I do not see the solution without a $\sqrt{3}$ on the OEIS page. If you read up about linear homogeneous recurrences, you'll see why they generally contain irrational (but not transcendental) terms (they are related to roots of a particular polynomial).

Comment: Oh ok, that is very interesting! Thanks for your response- I will look into this and hopefully it is possible without irrational numbers.